# Kitchen faucet low cold water pressure

Tags: kitchen-sink

Can anyone identify the manufacturer of my kitchen faucet from this picture of this logo? The faucet has low pressure of cold water only. Hot water OK.[image]

Answer (score 1):

Cut off the water under the sink and remove the cartridge and examine it. Maybe you will see what's wrong and you can repair it and re-install it. Probably you should just take the cartridge to a big box store (or to a good plumbing supply) and get a replacement.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and see if Lowes/Home Depot has a cartridge

Comment: Many times just some scale , lime , tiny rocks are built up removing the cartridge and flushing may clear it up.

Answer (score 0):

That hot/cold designation on the front of the handle screams Price Pfister.

Moen/Delta/Kohler general try to hide that, or not include it, in their design of that style of faucet.